# Where to add ahref link to html

Tags: html, shopify, e-commerce, liquid

I am currently editing CSS and HTML to a Shopify theme we (my company) are using for our new ecommerce site. I am trying to link star ratings positioned in the product grid to link to further down the page. The link is "#shopify-product-reviews", and I'm able to make it work on Google dev tools, but no luck when I go in to actually edit the html in Shopify.

Any help would be very appreciated!

This is the code:

````
          <span class="shopify-product-reviews-badge" data-id="{{ product.id }}">
            <span class="spr-badge">
              <span class="spr-starrating spr-badge-starrating">
                <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty"></i>
                <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty"></i>
                <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty"></i>
                <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty"></i>
                  <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty"></i>
              </span>
              </span>
          </span>
          </div>```
````

Comment: The good people at https://stamped.io have excellent support, I would contact them in the first instance

Comment: Are stamped.io the developers of this Shopify app? Surely I can't sign up to something, not purchase any of their apps and ask for help on someone else's app?

Comment: Oh, my bad... spr is "Shopify Product Reviews" not "Stamped..."

Answer (score 0):

I think you could wrap your whole code snippet in a link tag:

```
<a href="#shopify-product-reviews">
  <span class="shopify-product-reviews-badge" data-id="{{ product.id }}">
    <span class="spr-badge">
      <span class="spr-starrating spr-badge-starrating">
        <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty"></i>
        <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty"></i>
        <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty"></i>
        <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty"></i>
        <i class="spr-icon spr-icon-star-empty"></i>
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Tried that. Tried inserting a link tag in all possible sections of this code and still nothing :/

Comment: Is there an existing click event on the badge?

Comment: Nope. Or at least there shouldn't be.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the live code or a reduced reproduction of it somewhere?